# JPA and HTML table

Tags: java, jpa

How can I put the data from database into HTML table with JPA?

I am using this code but it's not working. Should I try to write a query to list all the data from database?

```jsp
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
        <title>MobMel::Index</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="songsdiv">
            <table class="table">
                <tr>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
                <%                
                    try {
                        PesmeFacadeLocal pf = (PesmeFacadeLocal) request.getAttribute("Pesme");
                        for (Pesme p : pf.findAll()) {
                %>
                <tr>
                    <td class="name"><%=p.getNaziv()%></td>
                    <td class = "genre"><%=p.getTip()%></td>
                </tr>
                <%
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                %>
                <tr>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is not working for you?

Comment: Why don't you use JSF? As described, for instance, in this tutorial: http://oxygen.informatik.tu-cottbus.de/webeng/JavaJpaJsfApp/index.html

Comment: JPA is nothing to do with displaying data. It puts data in a database.

Comment: Why do you need to store your service/EJB `PesmeFacadeLocal` as an HTTP Servlet request attribute as the code implies to be so?